# SoundCloud widget on Chromecast - dismissing popups

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, chromecast

Using the SoundCloud widget on Chromecast. After a few seconds of playing, something like this pops up. Besides being annoying, there's no way to dismiss on Chromecast. Anyone know how to turn this off or dismiss programatically in javascript?

[image: SoundCloud Explore]

Comment: Anybody, anything?

Comment: just needed to update to the latest version

Comment: Updated to the latest version

src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.1.js"

But the same problem persists although not every time, just occasionally. The Explore popup appears immediately and on Chromecast the user cannot dismiss. Anyone from SoundCloud who can give some pointers as to how to proceed?